Monoaural masking audio
"I would like to create a hidden suggestion, for which I want to use monoaural masking. This involves masking a calculated frequency for 200 microseconds. Specifically, if the signal level exceeds 0.1 volts, its frequency is calculated, and a signal with a duration of 200 microseconds should be added to the main audio stream. However, I am having issues with this. Firstly, the algorithm is very slow. Secondly, the algorithm is producing some strange results. The output sound resembles waves. Can you help me?"

import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import sounddevice as sd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
initial_directory = "/home/"
def normalize_audio(data):
"""Нормализация до диапазона -1 до 1"""
data = data/np.max(np.abs(data))
positive_signal = np.maximum(data, 0)
return positive_signal
def apply_masking(data, rate):
"""Применение маскировки частот"""
n = len(data)
spectrum = np.fft.rfft(data)
frequencies = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, 1 / rate)
masked_spectrum = spectrum.copy()

for i, amp in enumerate(np.abs(spectrum)):
    if amp > 0:
        freq = frequencies[i]
        masking_freq = freq + 10  # Маскирующая частота на 10 Гц выше
        masking_amp = amp * 2  # Амплитуда маскирующей частоты в 2 раза больше
        if masking_freq < rate / 2:
            idx = np.argmin(np.abs(frequencies - masking_freq))
            masked_spectrum[idx] += masking_amp * np.exp(1j * np.angle(spectrum[i]))

masked_audio = np.fft.irfft(masked_spectrum, n=n)
return masked_audio

def process_audio(file_path):
"""Обработка аудио файла"""
fs, data = wav.read(file_path)
data = stereo_to_mono(data)
data = normalize_audio(data)
# Разбиение на сегменты
segment_size = 10 * fs  # 10 секунд сегменты
num_segments = int(np.ceil(len(data) / segment_size))

processed_data = []
for i in range(num_segments):
    start = i * segment_size
    end = min((i + 1) * segment_size, len(data))
    segment = data[start:end]

    # Применение маскировки
    masked_segment = apply_masking(segment, fs)
    processed_data.append(masked_segment)

# Объединение сегментов
data = np.concatenate(processed_data)
data = normalize_audio(data)  # Вторичная нормализация после обработки

# Преобразование в 16-битный формат перед сохранением
data_int16 = np.int16(data * 32767)

# Диалоговое окно для выбора пути сохранения файла
save_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
    defaultextension=".wav",
    filetypes=[("WAV files", "*.wav")],
    initialfile=os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0] + "_processed.wav",
    title="Save the processed audio file"
)

if save_path:
    # Сохранение обработанного аудио
    wav.write(save_path, fs, data_int16)
    print(f"Файл сохранен как {save_path}")

    # Воспроизведение обработанного аудио
    sd.play(data, fs)
    sd.wait()

def stereo_to_mono(data):
"""Конвертация стерео в моно"""
if len(data.shape) == 2:
return np.mean(data, axis=1)
return data
def open_file():
"""Открытие диалогового окна для выбора файла"""
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=initial_directory, filetypes=[("WAV files", "*.wav")])
if file_path:
process_audio(file_path)
Интерфейс Tkinter
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Audio Processor")
open_button = tk.Button(root, text="Open Audio File", command=open_file)
open_button.pack()
root.mainloop()

